# Calculate font-size required for text to fill desired space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, text-size

How to calculate the font-size required for a text element to fill desired space? For example:

```
txt = "this text should fill the div precisely"
el = $("<div/>")
    .html(txt)
    .width(200)
    .css({
        fontFamily: "arial",
        fontSize: font_size_to_fit(txt,"arial",200)
    });
```

Edit: I am asking for a function that **calculates** the size based in a straighforward mathematical formula. It can be an approximation. **The solution proposed on the question above is not correct** because it involves an interactive DOM manipulation which is too heavy to be placed in a bottleneck area.

Comment: Make the text in another div/container and check the width until it matches.

Comment: This is a trickier problem than it looks at first, because most browsers enforce a minimum font size. So if you use a loop to continually shrink the font, you also have to test to see if the actual font size is the same as the font size you just specified. If it's not, you've reached the minimum and need to cancel your loop.

Comment: I appreciate the input but this is a different situation. On that question it is asked for a method to dynamically fit a text in an element - which is what the solution does, using a while. I am asking for a function that will **calculate** the required width. My function will be placed in a bottleneck area so it must be a fast mathematical formula, not an iterative DOM manipulation.

Comment: Can you use a monospace font?

Comment: I think that marking this as a duplicate is missing the comment the OP made.  @Viclib is looking for a **formula** or some other reasonable time algorithm that doesn't simply try many sizes as done in most of the suggestions in this or the recommended question.

Comment: @Viclib: You might be interested in my answer, posted after this was (incorrectly?) marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @answerers, I am a little busy with a work right now but I will come back here to review the answers when I resume the development of the app that involved this problem, hopefully, soon. (Also, if possible, please mark to reopen as this was probably closed by a misunderstanding.) Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried this, and perhaps it's crazy, but instead of all the (unfortunately unhelpful) suggestions to approach this by changing sizes over and over until the text fits, perhaps you could try just two very different font sizes (using no-wrap, of course) such as 10 and 100 and then interpolate or extrapolate your expected value assuming that the relationship should be nearly linear?  I don't know if doing two layouts like this is too expensive for your bottleneck.  If so, I'm not sure what hope you really have, as fonts can be tricky.  But this might work.

**Update**: I've created a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/RgZA7/)** using this technique.  It seems to work reasonably well.  The relevant code is:

```
var font_size_to_fit = (function() {
    var $test = $("<span/>").appendTo("body").css({
        visibility: "hidden", 
        border: 0, 
        padding: 0, 
        whiteSpace: "pre"
    });
    var minFont = 10, maxFont = 100; 
    return function(txt, fontFamily, size) {
        $test.appendTo("body").css({fontFamily: fontFamily}).text(txt);
        $test.css({fontSize: maxFont + "px"});
        var maxWidth = $test.width();
        $test.css({fontSize: minFont + "px"});
        var minWidth = $test.width();
        var width = (size - minWidth) * (maxFont - minFont) / 
            (maxWidth - minWidth) + minFont;
        $test.detach();
        return width + "px";
    };
}());
```

This would probably also need some error-checking to ensure we have no division by zero, which would occur when `minWidth == maxWidth`, most likely when the text supplied is empty.  That's left as an exercise for the reader.

**Another update**: This broke at some point.  I updated the Fiddle to include  this:

```
        return (width - .1) + "px";
```

This fixes an error noted in the comments.  But I have no idea what has changed to make it break in between.

Comment: Works like a charm in my app, and for me, this should be the answer for this question. :) I need the calculations to be fast so this approach is really better for me.

Comment: @licancabur: Glad it works for you.  I've never actually had call for it myself.  But it looked as though it would work.

Comment: The fiddle didn't work for me on Chrome. I had to tweak a few things: http://jsfiddle.net/webxl/1f0g40bn/

Comment: @webXL: Interesting.  I don't know why that broke.  I updated the fiddle to include a fudge-factor on the final return, and it seems ok now.

Answer (score 2):

```
function font_size_to_fit(text, fontFamily, divSize) {
  var tester = $("<div/>")
  .appendTo("body")
  .css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: "-9999px",
    fontFamily: fontFamily })
  .html(text);

  var width;
  var fontSize = 72;
  do {
    tester.css("fontSize", fontSize);
    fontSize -= 1;
    width = tester.width();
  } while (!(width <= divSize && width >= divSize * .98));
  return fontSize;
}
```

Maybe something like that? (Note: Doesn't address potential browser minimum font-sizes, didn't want to make the loop too complex.)

(Edited once to fix some potential bugs)

Answer (score 2):

**[FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)** is a great jQuery plugin for this.

It will resize fluidly (as the element changes size it will modify the font-size, not just on document ready or load), allows for min and max font sizes, and has some other options to allow you to tweak its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/XP8Gw/)

```
var x = 1;
var y = 20; //staring font-size
txt = "this text should fill the div precisely";
$('#element').html(txt).width(200).height(30).css('font-family', 'arial');
while (x == 1) {
    var element = document.querySelector('#element');
    if ((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)) {
        element.style.background = "yellow";
        element.style.fontSize = parseInt(y) + 'px';
        y--;
    } else {
        x = 0;
        element.style.background = "blue";
    }
}
```